# Similarity method Transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, transport-equation

I'm trying to use the similarity method/dilation to solve the linear transport equation

$u_t+cu_x=0$. 
I make the following coordinate transformation: $(x,t)\mapsto (z,s)$
I apply the transformation $z=\epsilon^ax$ and $s=\epsilon^bt$.

The PDE becames $\epsilon^{b-c}v_s-k\epsilon^{a-c}v_z$=0

I think this is invariant when $c=a-b$.

I am unsure if the above steps are correct, or how to derive the ODE associated with this transformed PDE. I know once I solve the ODE I am basically done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OP, it is shown that the advection equation $u_t + cu_x = 0$ is invariant by uniform dilatation of space and time, i.e. $(x,t) \mapsto (\alpha x, \alpha t)$. Therefore, we seek the similarity solution as $u(x,t) = v(\xi)$ where $\xi = x/t$. Injecting this *Ansatz* in the PDE gives
$$ \frac{c-\xi}{t} v'(\xi) = 0 \, . $$
Hence, the only smooth similarity solution is constant. The similarity method is more interesting in the case of nonlinear conservation laws.

Comment: AFAIK, the most general solution of the transport (advection) equation is $u=f(x-ut)$, in which $f(x)$ is the initial condition. The similarity solutions of linear parabolic equations are very interesting too.